# Flex 3/JS - 407 error when opening a sqeezebox

Tags: javascript, flex3, mootools, http-status-code-407, squeezebox

I need to open a link using a squeezebox (in combination with the mootools 1.2.4).
So, I've created a test.js (which contains a function to open a squeezebox), a Test.mxml application (containing a button that calls the js function) and I added all the scripts in the html page.

test.js:

```
function openSqueezeBox(url){

    alert("Tentative d'ouverture de: " + url);
    SqueezeBox.initialize();
    SqueezeBox.open(url);

};
```

Test.mxml:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function btnHandler1(e:MouseEvent):void{
            ExternalInterface.call("openSqueezeBox", 'http://www.google.com');
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Button label="google" click="btnHandler1(event)"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

When launching the application and clicking the button, I do get the alert window. However, the squeezebox is not opening. I get a 407 error: proxy authentication required.
I am indeed behind a proxy in my workplace, however the application is launched in a browser window that's already authenticated...

I do not really now what to do to get it work >_< 
So if anyone can enlighten me, it'd be really appreciated =)

Thanks a lot for your time ;)
Regards,
BS_C3

Comment: not sure. this squeezeBox is a bit dated now, does not even use Class and is setup as a singleton with its own pseudo constructor... do you get any exceptions you can trap? what version of mootools are you bundling with it?

Comment: mootools 1.2.4. I'm not getting any exception besides the 407 error in the firebug console.

Comment: so it's opening a new session then... odd. what happens when you try to use the adopt func and grab something from your dom (if you have one)? `SqueezeBox.open($('welcome'), {handler: 'adopt'});` instead of doing ajax - also, `Squeezebox.open` calls `this.initialize()` internally so it may not be needed. Keep in mind that opening up google.com may be subject to XSS / same origin policy restrictions for ajax or is flex not subject to that?

Answer (score 0):

External pages are loaded in an IFrame. You can try to load images or normal elements in the SB and see if it throws the same error.